# Generic Solution to extract xyz part of string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I need a generic solution to extract `xyz`  part from a String in SQL Server.

I am extracting **CLI** from input (e.g: `CLI = 2138132`) :

> sip:2138132@172.29.0.2

As :

```
CASE WHEN F.ANI = 'null' THEN ' ' 
     ELSE SUBSTRING(F.ANI,(CHARINDEX(':',F.ANI) + 1),(CHARINDEX('@', F.ANI)-5)) END AS 'CLI',
```

For the time being it was working fine but yesterday I noticed some error in my Stored Procedures because the automated machine IVR is now giving me invalid format input.

[image: Kindly review attached screenshot for your reference]

Comment: What does `= 'null'`mean? Do you store the character value 'null'?

Comment: Yes sometime I get null from application just to handle this I used this condition.

Comment: So you get `null` or `'null'`?

Comment: This is not the point... I am asking something else in the above question not about the null.

Comment: try  Replace `msml=` with `''`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one generic solution. Depending on your indexing, it might be faster or slower than @JaydipJ's suggestion of using `REPLACE` to eliminate `msml=`.

```
CASE WHEN F.ANI = 'null' THEN ' ' 
     ELSE SUBSTRING(F.ANI,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',F.ANI),(CHARINDEX('@', F.ANI)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',F.ANI))) END AS 'CLI'
```

This uses `PATINDEX` to find the first instance of a numeric character. It won't work in the scenario that your data contains numbers in the section at the start of the string that you want to ignore.